# Background Task returning null string using Fatsecret rest api

Tags: java, android, rest

I'm trying to use the [Fatsecret](https://platform.fatsecret.com/docs/guides) Rest api endpoint `foods/search` to return nutritional values based on food objects related to the search expression in the parameter. The Problem I'm encountering is in my background async task that makes the call to the above endpoint.

```
    void requester(){
    
    class GetRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String result="";
            BufferedReader bufferedReader=null;
            try {

             /* Global string variable that contains the request */

                URL url = new URL(apiUrle); 



                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String json;
                while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                    sb.append(json+"\n");
                }

                result =  sb.toString();
                

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.getMessage();
        }
      
      
        
            return result;
         
        }
        
         @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                
                Log.d("YOUR RESULT", result+"230");/* result string appears empty in logcat since it only displays string 230*/
            }
        
    }
    GetRequest ret = new GetRequest();
    ret.execute();
}
```

The main problem is that the `string(result)` returned is empty. I validated that Im not sending a wrong consumer key or secret by using the same values on a java application and I had no problem.
I also entered the apiUrl value in my browser and got the results I expected below.

```
   { "foods": { "food": [ {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 197kcal | Fat: 7.79g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 29.80g", "food_id": "1641", "food_name": "Chicken Breast", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-breast-ns-as-to-skin-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 110kcal | Fat: 1.24g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 23.09g", "food_id": "4881229", "food_name": "Skinless Chicken Breast", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-breast-skinless" }, {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 239kcal | Fat: 13.60g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 27.30g", "food_id": "448901", "food_name": "Grilled Chicken", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-grilled-ns-as-to-skin-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 247kcal | Fat: 15.49g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 25.06g", "food_id": "1695", "food_name": "Chicken Thigh", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-thigh-ns-as-to-skin-eaten" }, {"brand_name": "Valbest", "food_description": "Per 4 oz - Calories: 130kcal | Fat: 3.00g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 26.00g", "food_id": "3946778", "food_name": "Chicken Breast", "food_type": "Brand", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/valbest\/chicken-breast" }, {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 216kcal | Fat: 11.15g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 27.03g", "food_id": "1677", "food_name": "Chicken Drumstick", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-drumstick-ns-as-to-skin-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 239kcal | Fat: 13.60g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 27.30g", "food_id": "419178", "food_name": "Rotisserie Chicken", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-rotisserie-ns-as-to-skin-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 101g - Calories: 190kcal | Fat: 7.41g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 28.93g", "food_id": "1628", "food_name": "Roasted Broiled or Baked Chicken (Skin Not Eaten)", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-roasted-broiled-or-baked-skin-not-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 96g - Calories: 279kcal | Fat: 16.60g | Carbs: 9.59g | Protein: 21.45g", "food_id": "1636", "food_name": "Baked or Fried Coated Chicken with Skin (Skin\/Coating Eaten)", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/generic\/chicken-coated-baked-or-fried-prepared-with-skin-skin-coating-eaten" }, {"food_description": "Per 100g - Calories: 237kcal | Fat: 11.89g | Carbs: 0.00g | Protein: 30.42g", "food_id": "34511", "food_name": "Chicken Meat (Stewing, Stewed, Cooked)", "food_type": "Generic", "food_url": "http:\/\/www.fatsecret.com\/calories-nutrition\/usda\/chicken-meat-(stewing-stewed-cooked)" } ], "max_results": "10", "page_number": "0", "total_results": "5362" }}
```

Otherwise yeah ,I dont know what I could be missing so any insight will deeply be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that an exception is thrown. You can print it using `e.printStackTrace()`. `e.getMessage()` returns string, but it doesn't print anything.

Comment: Yah thanx...it was throwing an unknown host exception..